# Cannot delete vpc of AWS using ansible

Tags: ansible, aws-sdk, aws-opsworks

Have created a vpc with a subnet. Deleted the instance in that subnet. So, the subnet and vpc doesn't contain any more instances(dependencies).

Further, the vpc can be deleted from the console. But when attempted through ec2_vpc module, gives the error stating "dependencies are present under this vpc so cannot be deleted". But it can see deleted from the console.

So thought that subnet under this vpc may be the dependency. The ansible documentation provides module for subnet but when used it gives the module doesn't exist stating "illegal parameter"

The image showing the route table which cannot be deleted by snippet given by olle

[IMG]http://i59.tinypic.com/2d7xwxt.png[/IMG]

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the error you get when calling your play to remove the VPC? Also the error when removing subnets

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am seeing this same thing over two years later.

Comment: @darkwing I think the culprit was some subnets or route table that you have to delete it first, before deleting the VPC. Not sure though Now, am not using ansible.

Comment: Thanks, my problem was basically that I had created extra components attached to the VPC during development that were no longer covered (e.g. the name had changed) by my "destroy AWS" playbook

Answer (score 1):

I am using this code to create a VPC with ansible

```
- name: create a VPC
  local_action:
    module: ec2_vpc
    state: present
    cidr_block: 10.0.0.0/16
    resource_tags: "{}"
    subnets:
      - cidr: 10.0.0.0/16
    internet_gateway: True
    route_tables:
      - subnets:
          - 10.0.0.0/16
        routes:
          - dest: 0.0.0.0/0
            gw: igw
    region: '{{ region }}'
    wait: yes
  register: vpc
```

and the following two commands to remove it.

The first command removes the subnets, the IGW and the routing tables.

```
- name: remove subnets and route tables from VPC
  local_action:
    module: ec2_vpc
    vpc_id: "{{ vpc.vpc_id }}"
    region: "{{ region }}"
    state: present
    resource_tags: "{}"
    subnets: []
    internet_gateway: False
    route_tables: []
    wait: yes
```

and then I can remove the actual VPC

```
- name: delete VPC
  local_action:
    module: ec2_vpc
    vpc_id: "{{ vpc.vpc_id }}"
    region: "{{ region }}"
    state: absent
    resource_tags: "{}"
    wait: yes
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This perfectly works for deleting the internet gateways and subnets. It deletes route tables too but it doesn't delete the main route table associated with this vpc. So, still getting the dependency error because of one route table. I will edit my question to add the image showing the route table that needs to be deleted to avoid this error.

Comment: Moreover I use set_facts and the scope of this is host level. So when I use this in other hosts, should use with jinja 2 template. It works if the set_fact is retrieved in the same playbook but when I use in different playbook, it is not persisted. Is the implementation is wrong or should I use redis for fact caching to persist across playbooks.

Comment: now all the subnets, Internet gateway, route tables associated with the subnet has been deleted but the main route table cannot be deleted. And so this still gives dependency sir when deleting the vpc itself

Answer (score 1):

Ansible has provided ec2_vpc_net module for VPC, you can create or delete the VPC. 
Ex:

```
- name: DELETE THE VPC
  ec2_vpc_net:   
    name: vpc_name  
    cidr_block: "{{ build_env.vpc_net_cidr }}".  
    region: "{{ build_env.region }}"  
    profile: "{{ build_env.profile }}"  
    state: absent  
    purge_cidrs: yes  
    register: vpc_delete
```

Hope this helps